# How can I do the threads go ahead and start other function - C++ with OpenMP?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have experience with parallel loops and sections with OpenMP in C++, but now I need to make the threads go ahead and start a function while one thread keep running a forner function

The function table_builder_1 create a matrix and after all threads finish running, only one thread start to write the matrix in a file (currently all others threads wait for him) .

**1.** How can I do the threads go ahead and start the function table_builder_2?
**2.** After the writer thread finish he will join with others?

```
int main{

Class foo

foo.table_builder_1;
foo.table_builder_2;


return 0;
}



void foo:table_builder_1{

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
    for (int i = 0; i < N_size; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < N_size; j++) {
         create table
    }
}

\\write the table in file: 
file.write (Table) 


return;
}
```

Remark: **1.** I can’t parallelize the write because the data need to be ordered. **2.** The function table_builder_2 do the same as table_builder_1

Comment: Could you add valid c++ code, please? Also if both functions do the same why do you have two functions in the first place instead of one? Regarding remark 1: doing parallel writes to io hardware is never a good idea.

Comment: I will edit a simplified code and post it as soon as it's over. The functions do almost the same thing, the idea is the same. Between the functions I check if the file exists, if not the creation function is executed.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good case for `#pragma omp single nowait`.

`#pragma omp single` specifies that a section of code should be executed by single thread (not necessarily the master thread) (from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441767/difference-between-omp-critical-and-omp-single#33442011))

The `nowait` clause prevents the other threads from waiting for the thread that writes.